# how to define a parameter in the launch file?

Tags: c++, parameters, yaml, ros, launch

I have the following launch file, in which I am defining a parameter:

```
<launch>
<arg name="coordinates_file" value="$(find pkg_name)/name_of_the_txt_file.txt"/>
  <node pkg="pkg_name" type="ros_node_name" name="launch_file_name">
    <rosparam file="$(arg coordinates_file)"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Also, I am reading the parameter as following in the ros_node:

```
  ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
  std::string param="waypoints_cordinates.txt";
  std::string wp_file;
  wp_file = nh.getParam("wp_file", param);
  std::cout << "param1" << param  << std::endl;
  std::cout << "param" << wp_file  << std::endl;
```

While doing roslaunch to the mentioned launch file, I am facing the following error:

```
RLException: error loading <rosparam> tag: 
        'param' attribute must be set for non-dictionary values
XML is <rosparam file="$(arg wp_file)"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Could you please help me in solving the problem? Did I miss any part of creating and reading a param?!

Comment: Looks like a problem with the content of your param file. You should add it to the question.

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg but here is all what I have in the code, I mean the param is define as an arg in the launch file, should I do anything further?

Comment: Yes, you are referencing a file which should contain some parameters. Where is this file?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg this file is a .txt file, at the directory /home/catkin_ws/

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg the file content is:
1, 1, 2.5, 40, 45
0, 1, 40, 45, 2
0, 9.5, 40, 5, 5

Comment: This is no valid content. See: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam

Answer (score 0):

[Rosparam](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam) is usually used for setting multiple ROS params at once. Your issue occurs because nothing is being passed as an argument to the `rosparam` tag, so `rosparam` thinks that the user is trying to set a single parameter to a value but hasn't provided the parameter name to set on the parameter server. The error message relates to this sort of usage: `<rosparam param="a_list">[1, 2, 3, 4]</rosparam>`.

To solve your problem you need to pass a valid file name to your launch file. See the docs [here](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Commandline%20Tools#Passing_in_args). From the command line it would be `roslaunch your_launch_file.launch coordinates_file:=your_file_name`. If you are including the file from another launch file you need the following in that launch file:

```
<include file="$(find your_package)/launch/your_launch_file.launch">
    <arg name="coordinates_file" value="your_file_name"/>
</include>
```